# Undefined or unspecified behaviour?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards

I was reading [this article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sequence-points-in-c-set-1/) and they use the following example to explain undefined behaviour:

```
// PROGRAM 1
#include <stdio.h>
int f1() { printf ("Geeks"); return 1;}
int f2() { printf ("forGeeks"); return 1;}
int main() 
{ 
  int p = f1() + f2();  
  return 0; 
}
```

However, it seems to be about the order in which subexpressions are evaluated, and according to C standard (Annex J.1), it is an unspecified behaviour and not an undefined behaviour:

> **Unspecified behavior:** The order in which subexpressions are evaluated and the order in which side effects
>   take place, except as specified for the function-call () , &&, || , ? : , and comma
>   operators (6.5)

Since I am very new to reading official specifications, I'm wondering if I did misunderstand the example or the documentation. I know this may seem very pedantic but I'm interested into learning these advanced topics the right way.

Comment: "*example to explain undefined behaviour*": The code shown does *not* invoke "Un*defined* Behaviour".

Comment: What is the question again? The above example seems undefined in the C specification. That means in different compilers, you may get different results.

Comment: @parallelhighway: Wrong. It explicitly is **unspecified**, as OP assumes, not undefined behaviour.

Comment: @parallelhighway I edited my question. Actually, they use this example to explain undefined behaviour, however according to the specification this should be an unspecified behaviour.

Comment: The article links to wikipedia articles but then confuses terms.

Comment: This phrase is incorrect, according to @Olaf: "The reason for undefined behavior in PROGRAM 1 is, the operator ‘+’ doesn’t have standard defined order of evaluation for its operands."

Comment: @Olaf you are correct, I got confused in the article as well. The article confuses the terms.

Comment: @parallelhighway: Wikipedia is a bad resource for standard interpretation. There is only one authoritative resource for standard behaviour: the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you have provided in the question is given wrong example of undefined behavior. Evaluation of `f1` and `f2` in `f1() + f2()` will be unspecified. Note that standard says about **side effects** along with the **order of evaluation**

> The order in which subexpressions are evaluated and the **order in which side effects take place** [...]

Side effects (output to the stdout) in the evaluation of `f1` and `f2` are not related and they are not causing any undefined behavior.

This is no different than the example below

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1, c;

c = a + b;
```

Order of evaluation of `a` and `b` is unspecified in the expression `a + b`.

Comment: There is a sequence point before and after each function call, so I don't think your modified program has UB either.

Comment: @zwol; Yes. But which function will be evaluated first? Suggested reading: [Is f()+g() undefined or merely unspecified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3951017/2455888)

Comment: Merely unspecified, just like in the original.  Your link agrees with me.

Comment: @zwol; I think I did a mistake. You are right actually.

Comment: Writing to stdout is a side-effect IMHO, but the fact that there are side effects in `f1` and `f2` does not produce Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @rici; Yes. My wording was incorrect. Thanks for pointing it out.